# Python. Connecting custom class to QThread

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots, qthread

In my app I have controll class defined as follow:

```
class Controller(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_myUI):
```

In this class in the button clicked action i would like to connect the finished() action of QThread to the `done` method defined in `Controller` class as follows:

```
def applyAction(self):
    self.myTread = MyTestTread()
    self.connect(self.myTread, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.done)
    self.myTread.start()
```

But this code returns the follwing error:

```
AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `connect` function that you're trying to use is a staticmethod of QObject.  This example is from the [docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide):

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton("Call someFunc")
QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()'), someFunc)
```

It seems to me you want to replace your second line in `applyAction` with:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.myTread, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.done)
```

Note that this syntax is long ago deprecated (since Qt 4.5).  The new way is:

```
self.myTread.finished.connect(self.done)
```